# Turn logging to lldb console off (Socket IO framework for iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I am using [pkyeck / socket.IO-objc](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) framework. It is very good, however I am unable to debug with the verbose logs it produces to the lldb, which makes the console constantly full with descriptions about traffic, which are useless to me at the moment. I couldn't find a way how to turn it **OFF**. Anybody knows how to do it? I just can't imagine myself commenting out all the lines with NSLog...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It is rather undesired to tinker with the source code of the framework - usually it is a good practice to take it **AS-IS** but since there wasn't any other way...

In the file **SocketIO.m**, locate line numbers *32 - 39*:

```
#define DEBUG_LOGS 1
#define DEBUG_CERTIFICATE 1

#if DEBUG_LOGS
#define DEBUGLOG(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DEBUGLOG(...) 
#endif
```

Naturally, everybody now knows what comes next - change the value of **DEBUG_LOGS** to **0**.

That's it, done. I recommend adding a *//TODO:* to the line above in order not to forget for the next time, when debugging logs are desired.

Comment: They should have surrounded their `#define DEBUG_LOGS 1` with `#ifndef DEBUG_LOGS ... #endif` and given it a more unique name. This annoys me.